# Problems related to expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Here are two exercises on the text of Kai-Lai Chung that I am working on:

For any distributive function such that $F(0-)=0$, then
$$\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))dx=\int_0^\infty xdF(x)\le+\infty$$

I think this could be done by integration by parts. However, it seems to me if $1-F(x)$ goes at the order of $1/x$, then $\int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx\sim \int_0^\infty 1/x\ dx$ is not even finite! Is this really true for any distributive function?

Another exercise is:

If $p>0$, $E(|X|^p)<\infty$, then $x^p P(X>x)=o(1)$ as $x\to\infty$. Conversely, if $x^p P(X>x)=o(1)$ as $x\to\infty$, then  $E(|X|^{p-\epsilon})<\infty$ for $0<\epsilon<p$.

For the first statement, I thought about using $EX^p=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}P(X>x)dx$ to get a similar expression, but then got stuck. For the converse one, it gives a feeling of Hölder's inequality as what we have done in showing $L^p\subset L^q$ for $1\le p\le q<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{\infty} (1-F(x))dx=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{(x,\infty]} dF(y)dx=\int  \int_0^{y}dx dF(y)=\int ydF(y)$ where I have used Fubini/Tonelli's theorem to interchange the integrals.

Comment: But how to assure that the integral is finite?

Comment: For Tonelli's Theorem you don't require finiteness of the integral. As long as the integrand is non-negative and measurable we can always interchange the integrals. @Apocalypse

Comment: Oh that’s the cool thing about Tonelli’s Theorem! Thank you!